# Sublime 3 Path Variables

Tags: python-3.x, path, installation, windows-10, sublimetext3

I am trying to set up a python 3 build path for sublime text 3 on a windows 10 pc. The system says that it cannot find the specified file, but I have already added the path and set the build system for python3. The error message I get when I try to build is below..

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

[cmd: ['python3', '-i', '-u', 'C:\\Users\\strinkjr\\Desktop\\Python Stuff\\errorSearch.py']]

[dir: C:\Users\strinkjr\Desktop\Python Stuff]

[path: C:\Users\strinkjr\Desktop\Python Stuff\]

[Finished]
```

My build environment file is as follows:

```json
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"C:/Users/strinkjr/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

I am unsure if I set up the path incorrectly or if I set up the build environment incorrectly. (Maybe both)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of overall problems you're having that are standing in your way here.

The first is that you didn't set the `PATH` correctly. The build output shows you the `PATH` as it's currently defined as far as the command execution is concerned:

```
[path: C:\Users\strinkjr\Desktop\Python Stuff\]
```

The `PATH` is the list of locations where windows will look for the program that you're trying to execute, so unless there is a `python3.exe` in this directory you've accidentally set the `PATH` to the location of the files that you're running and not the interpreter that's used to run them.

Secondly you're passing `-i` to the Python interpreter to get it to drop into interactive mode once it's done executing the script. Sublime doesn't let you interact with programs that you execute from within a `sublime-build`, so if you do this once your program finishes executing and goes into interactive mode, it's going to be effectively hung waiting for you to provide it input that you can't provide.

Your build system also contains this `file_regex` entry:

```
"file_regex": "^[ ]File \"C:/Users/strinkjr/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/python.exe\", line ([0-9]*)",
```

In a `sublime-build` file, the `file_regex` is used to be able to detect what lines in the program's output are errors so that Sublime can allow you to navigate between errors or flag them with inline errors if you have that option turned on.

Although this won't stop your programs from running, it **will** stop Sublime from being able to recognize errors because the name of the file is never going to match.

I would try a `sublime-build` file something like the following and see if that works better for you:

```json
{
    "shell_cmd": "python3 -u \"$file\"",
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python",    

    "env": {
        "PYTHONIOENCODING": "utf-8",
        "PATH": "$PATH;C:/Users/strinkjr/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/"
    },
}
```

This removes the `-i` argument to stop the interpreter from going interactive in order to stop any problems and uses `shell_cmd` instead of `cmd` to provide the command, which changes the format slightly.

The `file_regex` here is one that will match regular python errors, which is similar to the one you already provided but without the reference to the Python executable.

The big addition here is a couple of environment variables. The first one ensures that Python knows that it should use `utf-8` to generate output, since that's what the Sublime console is expecting it to use. That stops you from getting potential errors if you try to display non-ascii output.

This also applies a new PATH that includes the existing path and also adds to it the path that looks like it might be where your Python is installed based on the files you were already using.

That part may need adjustment if the location is not correct; alternatively you can remove the `PATH` portion of the `sublime-build` and modify your `PATH` environment variable as appropriate instead. Note that you may need to restart Sublime if you do that in order for it to see the change.

Comment: Thanks for your help!